# In Bazor server I need js interop in OnAfterrender but .net 8 ssr mode does not letting this

Tags: server-side-rendering, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I need my site layout is in ssr mode. Since enabling interactivity causes child components to be also interactive.

But making the layout rendering static causes its onafterrender method and jsinterop that it contains disabled.

If these javascript codes aren't executed the entire site also is not loaded.

So my question is how jsinterop calls to be executed in component's (firstrender). When the blazor component is in .net 8 ssr (static server rendering mode)? Or any alternate ways to acheive this.

Comment: add a script tag to the component - that will run when it renders

Comment: I need the result of javascript (local storage) in c#. This is only possible with jsinterop.

Comment: That indicates you need the component to be interactive, so you should enable interactive rendering on that component

Comment: But if I enable interactivity in the layout component. All its child's will be also interactive. So it becomes like previous versions of blazor.

Comment: So make a component just for the bit that needs to be interactive? It's hard to say more without more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the BlazorPageScript Nuget package developed by Buck Mackinnon: https://github.com/MackinnonBuck/blazor-page-script

Just add the tag at the top of your page like:

```cs
@using BlazorPageScript
<PageScript Src="./Components/Elements/Header.razor.js"></PageScript>
```

and inside your JS you can use `onLoad`, `onUpdate` and `onDispose` methods.

Here an example:

```js
// This method is executed after enhanced form calls and once at startup
export function onUpdate() {
    const theDiv = 'theTimer';
    // Update the timer every second
    setInterval(updateTimer, 1000, theDiv);

    // Initialize the timer on load
    updateTimer(theDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could show the [splide](https://splidejs.com/) slider by [BlazorPageScript](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorPageScript/1.0.0#show-readme-container) nuget package that makes easy [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/static-server-rendering?view=aspnetcore-8.0) microsoft document for us.

Home.razor :

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorPageScript
@attribute [StreamRendering]
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
<PageScript Src="./Components/Pages/Public/Home.razor.js" />
```

Home.razor.js :

```
var counter = 0;

// execute first time
export function onLoad() { 
    mountSplide();
}

// execute after changing page and back again, for each data base calling(StreamRendering)
export function onUpdate() { 
    let tag = document.getElementsByClassName('splide');
    if (tag.length > 0)
        counter++;
    if (counter == 2) {
        mountSplide();
    }
}

// execute when leave the page
export function onDispose() {
    counter = 0;
}

function mountSplide() {
    let splide = new Splide('.splide', {
        type: 'loop',
        drag: 'free',
        focus: 'center',
        autoScroll: {
            speed: 1,
        },
        width: '50rem',
        autoplay: true,
        wheelSleep: 2000,
    });
    splide.mount();
}
```

The **counter value** depends on async database query calling count and blazor life cycles.